# How to create an UPDATE statement for merging duplicates across multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, window-functions

I was wondering if anybody would be able to help me with this `UPDATE` statement

I have around 300 or so customer records that includes data like addresses, inspection records, notes all across multiple tables. For example the customer's record would be on one table, their inspection records on another, their notes on another etc. They are linked together by a Customer ID.

So within these 300 records are duplicates (about half of them are). What I am trying to accomplish is an `UPDATE` statement that changes the ID of the duplicate record to the ID of the original record.

Effectively then merging all the other tables (inspections, notes) onto the original ID of the customer. I want to update each `CustomerID` on the other tables to be the first ID sequentially. So if the customer's first record has an ID of 1, and their duplicate record has an ID of 2, I want to update all of the 2's on the other tables to be 1.

Hopefully the below example can illustrate this better:

`CUSTOMER` table:

| CustomerID | Customer Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Jones |
| 2 | John Jones |
| 3 | David Philips |
| 4 | David Philips |

`INSPECTION` table (before update)

| InspectionID | CustomerID |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 |
| 001 | 2 |
| 001 | 3 |
| 001 | 4 |

`INSPECTION` table (after update):

| InspectionID | CustomerID |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 |
| 001 | 1 |
| 001 | 3 |
| 001 | 3 |

What I'm struggling to get my head around is how to get SQL to update the ID to the first ID sequentially.

Comment: And how would that statement look in an example? Sorry my SQL is very basic currently.

Comment: What you need is a mapping table between old customer ID (the duplicate) and new (the original). I don't know the method you use for calculating duplicates,but once you have that table, it's just a simple UPDATE, where you join every table against the mapping table by the old ID and set the new ID

Answer (score 1):

You can get duplicates using `ROW_NUMBER` or `FIRST_VALUE`. In this case `FIRST_VALUE` makes the most sense as you want to copy over the data from one ID to the other.

The `PARTITION BY` clause contains the columns that you want to distinct over. Make sure the `ORDER BY` is unique, such as by using the primary key.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
      FIRST_VALUE(c.CustomerID) OVER (PARTITION BY c.CustomerName ORDER BY c.CustomerID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS FirstID
    FROM CUSTOMER c
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cte.CustomerID <> cte.FirstID;
```

You can combine this with `UPDATE`s on the various other tables, eg

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
      FIRST_VALUE(c.CustomerID) OVER (PARTITION BY c.CustomerName ORDER BY c.CustomerID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS FirstID
    FROM CUSTOMER c
)
UPDATE i
SET CustomerID = cte.FirstID
FROM cte
JOIN INSPECTION i ON i.CustomerID = cte.CustomerID
WHERE cte.CustomerID <> cte.FirstID;
```

Finally delete the extra parent rows.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
      FIRST_VALUE(c.CustomerID) OVER (PARTITION BY c.CustomerName ORDER BY c.CustomerID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS FirstID
    FROM CUSTOMER c
)
DELETE cte
WHERE cte.CustomerID <> cte.FirstID;
```